# Is there any way to split a treesitter grammar into multiple files?

Tags: javascript, treesitter

I'm parsing a fairly simple language but my grammar is already becoming unwieldy in a single file. Is there any way to split it up into multiple files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, grammar files are evaluated with Node.js, so you can use the [`require`](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/what-is-require/)  function to split up grammars into files however you see fit.